# AccuRev : How to get all files changed?

Tags: accurev

I am looking to get list of files changes between a timestamp.
For example 2013/11/11 11:10:00-now.

accurev hist command given the files changed on that particular stream but it does not include the changes came from parent stream.

Is there a way to get the list of changes flew from parent streams?

Comment: "does not include the changes came from parent stream"  -- can't you use the '-s <stream>' switch to specify the parent stream instead of the current stream?

Answer (score 0):

Change the basis time of your child stream to the date of 2013/11/11 11:10:00.  Then perform a diff by files across the child and parent stream.

Answer (score 0):

Accurev 6 has added some new arguments for the diff command so the following should do the trick:

```
accurev diff -a -i -v MyStream -V MyStream -t "2013/11/11 11:10:00-now"
```

Alternatively you could try the [`accurev.py` script](https://github.com/orao/ac2git/blob/master/accurev.py), from the [ac2git repo](https://github.com/orao/ac2git/), which will return to you all the transactions that could have affected your stream. Run it like this:

```
python accurev.py deep-hist -p MyDepot -s MyStream -t "2013/11/11 11:10:00-now"
```